# Convert pandas columns values to row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a dataframe to long form.

The dataframe I am starting with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'],
                   ['d', 'e'], 
                   ['f', 'g', 'h'],
                   ['q', 'r', 'e', 't']])
df = df.rename(columns={0: "Key"})

    Key 1   2   3
0   a   b   None    None
1   d   e   None    None
2   f   g   h       None
3   q   r   e       t
```

The number of columns is not specified, there may be more than 4. There should be a new row for each value after the key

This gets what I need, however, it seems there should be a way to do this without having to drop null values:

```
new_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Key'])[['Key', 'value']]
new_df = new_df.dropna()


    Key value
0   a   b
1   d   e
2   f   g
3   q   r
6   f   h
7   q   e
11  q   t​
```

Comment: Hey! Are you trying to avoid the dropna for performance reasons or for memory?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ TBH I was doing this last night while tired and it felt like a bit of a hack in that I was afraid I would encounter unexpected behavior down the road. Thinking about it now and based on the answers it seems like it should be fine, though the solutions below are also very good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
You should be able to do this with `set_index` + `stack`:

```
df.set_index('Key').stack().reset_index(level=0, name='value').reset_index(drop=True)

  Key value
0   a     b
1   d     e
2   f     g
3   f     h
4   q     r
5   q     s
6   q     t
```

If you don't want to keep resetting the index, then use an intermediate variable and create a new DataFrame:

```
v = df.set_index('Key').stack()
pd.DataFrame({'Key' : v.index.get_level_values(0), 'value' : v.values})
```

```
  Key value
0   a     b
1   d     e
2   f     g
3   f     h
4   q     r
5   q     s
6   q     t
```

The essence here is that `stack` automatically gets rid of `NaN`s by default (you can disable that by setting `dropna=False`).

---

**Option 2**
More performance with `np.repeat` and numpy's version of `pd.DataFrame.stack`:

```
i = df.pop('Key').values
j = df.values.ravel()

pd.DataFrame({'Key' : v.repeat(df.count(axis=1)), 'value' : j[pd.notnull(j)]
})

  Key value
0   a     b
1   d     e
2   f     g
3   f     h
4   q     r
5   q     s
6   q     t
```

Answer (score 5):

By using `melt`(I do not think dropna create more 'trouble' here)

```
df.melt('Key').dropna().drop('variable',1)
Out[809]: 
   Key value
0    a     b
1    d     e
2    f     g
3    q     r
6    f     h
7    q     s
11   q     t
```

And if without `dropna`

```
s=df.fillna('').set_index('Key').sum(1).apply(list)
pd.DataFrame({'Key': s.reindex(s.index.repeat(s.str.len())).index,'value':s.sum()})


Out[862]: 
  Key value
0   a     b
1   d     e
2   f     g
3   f     h
4   q     r
5   q     s
6   q     t
```

Comment: Note that this is OP's solution, but ...`there should be a way to do this without having to drop null values`

Answer (score 2):

With a comprehension
This assumes the key is the first element of the row.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[k, v] for k, *r in df.values for v in r if pd.notna(v)],
    columns=['Key', 'value']
)

  Key value
0   a     b
1   d     e
2   f     g
3   f     h
4   q     r
5   q     s
6   q     t
```